# How to uninstall old versions of the kernel?

Tags: 10.04, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I to remove or hide old kernel versions, to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

How to uninstall old versions of the kernel?

The grub menu is full with old kernel entries, when i need to boot windows i have to press down key multiple times and i hate doing that, so please help me.

Ubuntu version : 10.04

Thank you in advance.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Go to synaptic package manager and search for 'linux-image'. Then select and remove the older versions. To remove right click on the package and select 'Mark for Removal'.